# publisher and subscriber in rosjava

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the publisher/subscriber tutorial for rosjava provided at this link.

http : //rosjava.github.io/rosjava_core/latest/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-java-package

However, when i copy paste the code into a file in my project, I am getting compilation errors like (1)package std_msgs does not exist and 2)cannot find symbol) when i build my package with catkin_make. I am using catkin_make for building because this tutorial says so:
--http ://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/hydro/Creating%20Rosjava%20Packages

I added my dependencies (rosjava_bootstrap,rosjava_build_tools,std_msgs,rosjava_messages) in my package.xml file like this.(i think i should be doing this in the gradle file)

<build_depend>rosjava_build_tools</build_depend>
<run_depend>rosjava_build_tools</run_depend>

How do I add the dependencies for the modules being imported in the begining of the publisher program. the modules are-

import org.ros.namespace.GraphName;
import org.ros.node.Node;
import org.ros.node.NodeMain;

Can somebody tell me how to add the dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101856/publisher-and-subscriber-in-rosjava/) by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-15**:
I am using ROS hydro.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-17**:
So you create a package following the second tutorial, and then you add the code from the first one? right? Can you just follow the second tutorial and compile without errors?

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-17**:
I couldnt find any code for publisher or subscriber for the second tutorial using catkin_make for building. I am pretty sure i need to add the dependencies in the gradle file but i dont know how. I read the gradle tutorial where it says i need to specify the version of the package too. How do i specify these packages [.org.ros.namespace.GraphName;  org.ros.node.Node; org.ros.node.NodeMain]according to the syntax given here for dependencies [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html]-go to example 7.4;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I think so; you add dependencies on build.gradle file. An example:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:[0.1,0.2)'
    compile 'org.ros.rosjava_messages:std_msgs:[0.5,0.6)'
}
```

not sure if this will work or you need something more.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-26**:
There are two build.gradle files. One in my package folder and one inside the project folder in my package folder. In which build.gradle file do i add this?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-26**:
Not fully sure what you mean with project and package... I think the one in project. Must have almost no additional contents. The one in the package contains some groovy functions.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-26**:
I created a pakcage called rosjava_foo and in that i created a project called dude as it is said in the tutorial. THere is one build.gradle in the rosjava_foo folder and one in the dude folder. The one in the dude folder has a section called "dependencies{      } " but it is commented between /* and */. The build.gradle in hte package folder has some commands like apply plugin etc along with the maven repository and the dependency block.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-26**:
Right; add dependencies to the one in the dude folder. Please mark the question as answered if it works to help others with the same problem.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-11-26**:
i added compile 'org.ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:[0.1,)' and the errors reduced from from 20 to 1.

The error I have now states that "GraphName(java.lang.String) has private access in org.ros.namespace.GraphName
return new GraphName("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener")

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-26**:
mmm... good improvement! Tutorial must be outdated; replace
new GraphName("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener")
with
GraphName.of("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener")

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-11-28**:
All works now? Please mark question as solved if so

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-12-26**:
If I do that then i get a new error. It says symbol not defined and the arrow points to the dot in GraphName.of .Appreciate all the help.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2013-12-27**:
Hi jorge..please take a look at my question. THanks

http://answers.ros.org/question/113431/rosjava-listener/